# Modification of Builder pattern, is it good practice?

Tags: java, factory, static-methods, builder

I am trying to establish mandatory condition in the code. The code goes like this:

```
public class Foo {
   public Type;
   public int planeId;
   public int carId;
   public int capacity;
   public String manufacturer;
   public int serialId;
   .. etc
}
```

Now `Type` is an enum, with AIRPLANE and CAR as 2 values. Condition is that if `Type` is plane, then planeId needs to be populated, else CarId has to be populated. Since `class Foo` has many params we chose builder pattern.

```
 public static class Builder {

    public Builder(public Type type, int id) {
        if (type == PLANE) {
          planeId = id;
        } else {
          carId = id;
        }
    }
```

But then I had an idea to fuse static factories into builder pattern

```
public static class Builder {

   public static Builder getPlaneBuilder(int id) {
     return new Builder(PLANETYPE, id); // calls private constructor

   }

   public static Builder getCarBuilder(int id) {
     return new Builder(CARTYPE, id);  // calls private constructor
}
```

I have never seen static factories fused into builders but they seem to do their job well. Any comments ? Critiques ? better solution ?

Comment: Did you just quickly type this as an example? I don't think any of those declarations in your second example will compile. Java has no object initializers.

Comment: yeah i typed but sort of fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Condition is that if Type is plane, then planeId needs to be
>   populated, else CarId has to be populated.

If `carId` is for `Car` object and `planeId` is for `Plane` object, should you not have two distinct classes to handle them and declare these fields only where these are required ?
Adding fields in both classes that are relevant only in a single class is probably not desirable. It decreases the cohesion of fields of the class.

About your question, using a factory method is of course a good idea.
It is in general helpful when you want to control the creation of the instance (for you it is already the case with the builder).
But it is also useful when you have multiple ways of constructing an object and that the constructor doesn't convey enough information about what you want to create.

For example it is a good example :

```
   public static Builder getPlaneBuilder(int id) {
     return new Builder(PLANETYPE, int id); // calls private constructor
   }
```

From the client code `getPlaneBuilder(int id)` is more meaningful than `public Builder(public Type type, int id)`.